# How to display a scrollable grid of images in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How can i display a scrollable grid of images in matlab GUI?

I want something similar to what is shown below

[image]

This stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288941/dynamic-grid-of-images-in-matlab) describes a way of displaying images in a uitable by setting the 'String' property to an HTML code pointing to an image. But this requires me to save the images to disk which is not an option i would like as these displays are fired up dynamically.

It would also be nice, if i could add a checkbox inside each image so the user can select a subset of them.

Comment: This is going to be hard to do in matlab.  Are you able to use .net or java?

Comment: No. I am not allowed to. If you are suggesting, calling java code from matlab (to use some undocumented gui functionality), then yes that would work. But, I guess matlab's gui functionality is way too primitive for such things.

Comment: Note that you can also save the images to web, if it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22387-imdisp) tool. In the gui, you should be able to scroll through. But to have title below every image you might have to edit the tool.

Sample output:
[a grid of images http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fx_files/22387/12/imdisp.jpg](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fx_files/22387/12/imdisp.jpg)

Comment: it is not scrollable - images are displayed on different pages.

Comment: I think we can add a scroll bar using uicontrol()

Comment: [This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5253-scrolling-figure-demo) demo shows how to enable scroll in a figure.

Comment: @prasanth. I found both the [original](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22387-imdisp) version mentioned by you and the [enhanced](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42685) version but i dint know how to scroll through them with a slider bar. Seems like, now, i have a solution in pieces. Will try to get them to work together and post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

[How can I use scrollbars in MATLAB figure windows when viewing large GUIs?](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-16B5M/index.html?solution=1-16B5M)

-> Note: This is a workaround, scrollbars are not available for Matlab-figures

I would suggest to use the tool Prashanth presented in his awnswer and combine it, by putting all elements within the panel.